# List down only specific type of files from SVN using command Line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, command-prompt, findstr

I am trying to list down the files recursively from svn using the 
command line input

```
svn ls https:/knode.Testing.com/trunk/ --depth infinity
```

but it's returning all the files from the svn path, but I don't want some of the files which end with .java and .jar I tried the following command

```
svn ls https:/knode.Testing.com/trunk/ --depth infinity | findstr /V ".java .jar"
```

It's not returning java and jar files but it's blocking some of the files like dll,html

how can I get the files except for Java and jar files,correct me if i made any mistake while using findstr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
svn ls https:/knode.Testing.com/trunk/ --depth infinity | findstr /R /V "\.java$ \.jar$"
```

With this way, you are using regex to exclude your file list (`/R`). This command should exclude all files ending with `.java` or `.jar`. Because you are using the regex way, you have to escape the dot `.` to `\.`. Also, the dollar sign `$` is defined  the end of line / filen

Comment: I am looking for any inbuild SVN command to filter out the files, but I didn't find anything. Thank you @kristian